Error importing data to EEGLAB using GNU Octave
I'm trying to use EEGLAB in GNU Octave to import EEG files. I've tried importing a .mat file using the biosig plugin, and I've tried importing an existing datafile using a .set file and the 'load existing dataset' option. In both instances, I've gotten the error:
EEGLAB error in function eeg_checkset() at line 1166:
'dipfitdefs' undefined near line 1166, column 13

The fact that I got the same error when trying two different methods to import different types of data files make me question if I have EEGLab downloaded properly, which I think I do. I am new to using GNU Octave, but I had EEGLab working properly in Matlab on a different computer previously, and followed the same steps for setup. When I try to import data, the EEGLab folder is set as the current folder in Octave. Where am I going wrong here?
I've tried importing both .mat files and .set files and have gotten the same error in both instances. The 'dipfitdefs' function seems to be downloaded correctly and is in the EEGLab plugins folder for dipfit.
